# get the target number using combination of operators in arraylist

Tags: java, data-structures

Trying to solve the below question
 example:
 **f(10, [1,2]) = false**. 
There's no way to add or subtract 1 and 2 to get 10.

**Test Case** 
fails for- f(1, [1]).

**Expected Output** 
 false

**Actual Output** 
 true

Where is my logic going wrong?

The method takes a magic number and a list of numbers. It should return true if it can insert, add or subtract operations in the list of numbers to get the magic number. Otherwise, it returns false.

**CODE**

```
if(magicNumber !=0 && (numbers == null || numbers.isEmpty())) 
return false;
boolean flag = true;
for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++) {
int requiredVal = magicNumber - numbers.get(i);
 for(int j=1; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
   if(requiredVal == numbers.get(j)) 
    return true;
   else if(requiredVal < numbers.get(j)) 
    requiredVal = requiredVal +   numbers.get(j);
   else requiredVal = requiredVal - numbers.get(j);
   }
   flag = false;
 }

return flag;   
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: My Test Case fails for- f(1, [1]). Expected output should be false, but I'm getting the value as true. Where is my logic going wrong?

Comment: Did you try [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: You would also get a wrong result in a case like f(1,[2,3,4]) where 1=2+3-4 but your algorithm returns false.

Comment: Check GitHub https://github.com/mloukili/math/blob/master/README.md for mathematical proof and java code. The trick is to prove that this is equivalent to: Find a sub array in a list of numbers where the sum of this subset equals to (S + M) / 2. Where S is the sum of all numbers and M is the magic number we are looking for. For example finding the magic number 2 by subtracting or adding numbers from [1, 2, 3, 4] is the same as finding 6 = [(S + M) / 2] by adding 1 or more numbers from the list.

Answer (score -1):

Default value of variable flag is true. In your code, the for loop not executing so it is returning the default value which is true. You need to change the default value of flag to false at line 3.

```
boolean flag = false;
```